# Считать файл blob из БД Oracle без записи его в ОЗУ C#

Tags: c#, база-данных, oracle, blob

Имеется БД Oracle, возникла необходимость скачивать blob в файл на компьютере. Как потоково читать blob из Oracle, чтобы не грузить его полностью в оперативную память?

Comment: [SqlClient Streaming Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sqlclient-streaming-support) - делать по аналогии. Вместо `GetStream` использовать `GetBlob`.

Comment: Проблема в том, что для работы с БД Oracle не получается использовать указанные в ссылке библиотеки.

Comment: чтобы прочитать блоб кусками разумного размера, вызывайте `dbms_lob.substr` в цикле.  чем это хуже потокового чтения?

Comment: Делайте "по аналогии" - что тут непонятно? OracleDataProvider. Метод GetBlob, который возвращает Stream. Это стрим сохраняем в файл. Всё! Делов на пару минут.

Comment: Всем спасибо! Все получилось, использовал dmbs_lob.substr